# How to specify a different home directory for an LDAP user on a local host

Tags: linux, ldap

So after reading all of the directory edit of an LDAP user my question still isn't answered.  I need to change an LDAP users home directory on just certain servers without changing it for every server.  Obviously I can't "add" the user while the host is connected via LDAP and when I try to manually edit the /etc/passwd file and then login the server says "user not found".  I have seen where the user is created locally before connecting the server to LDAP it works (I think) however I was hoping no to have to go that far.  Would it be something as simple as stopping SSSD, creating the user locally with the correct path, and then restarting it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the `/etc/nsswitch` to look against ldap from:

```
passwd: files ldap
```

to

```
passwd: files
```

You don't need to restart anything.
At this point you can just

```
useradd <user>
```

Then you can re-add the look up over ldap in the nsswitch.